# allow admin user edit others user flag field

Tags: flags

I have a flag named `buy`, with those field: `buy amount`, `comment`, `status`.

Users can `buy` a content with *buy how many content*(`buy amount`), and *leave a comment*(`comment`), and the default `status` is "wait for reviews"

**I want:**

Now I wanna allow site administrator to change the  `status` to "bought success" or "bought failed".

I create a view to list all been bought content, and I want to create a two button "set to bought success" and "set to bought failed" into the view.

**I tried:**

I try to install workflow module and attach workflow field to the flag. and add the workflow button to views.

Then I wanna to create a rule:

- Event: when flag field updated (actually this event is not exist)
- Condition: when the workflow field equals 'bought success'
- Actions: set the flag's workflow field to

**Problems**

1. Although the "set to bought success" and "set to bought failed" button in the view, but the when I click, not thing happend.
2. The rules not have the event of `when flag field updated`, and rules can not set the flag's field

How should I do?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to modify in the Content with example so that it is clearer?

Comment: @pritywiz, thanks for your reply, I updated my question, please help me again.